# NSDictionary annidate in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have this json result.
I would take the field "alert".
I try this:

```
var alert: NSString = jsonResult["features"]["properties"]["alert"]
```

but this is the error: does not have a member named 'subscript'.
I can not how to access a field in a nested dictionary

```
{
        features =     (
                    {
                geometry =             {
                    coordinates =                 (
                        "-97.95359999999999",
                        "37.2382",
                        5
                    );
                    type = Point;
                };
                id = usb000si7g;
                properties =             {
                    alert = green;
                    cdi = "5.8";
                    code = b000si7g;
                    detail = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/detail/usb000si7g.geojson";
                    dmin = "0.017";
                    felt = 1258;
                    gap = 38;
                    ids = ",usb000si7g,";
                    mag = "4.3";
                    magType = mwr;
                    mmi = "4.94";
                    net = us;
                    nst = "<null>";
                    place = "8km SE of Harper, Kansas";
                    rms = "0.51";
                    sig = 864;
                    sources = ",us,";
                    status = reviewed;
                    time = 1412272884590;
                    title = "M 4.3 - 8km SE of Harper, Kansas";
                    tsunami = "<null>";
                    type = earthquake;
                    types = ",cap,dyfi,general-link,geoserve,losspager,moment-tensor,nearby-cities,origin,phase-data,shakemap,tectonic-summary,";
                    tz = "-300";
                    updated = 1412614943519;
                    url = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/eventpage/usb000si7g";
                };
                type = Feature;
            }
        );
        metadata =     {
            api = "1.0.13";
            count = 1;
            generated = 1412617232000;
            status = 200;
            title = "USGS Significant Earthquakes, Past Week";
            url = "http://earthquake.usgs.gov/earthquakes/feed/v1.0/summary/significant_week.geojson";
        };
        type = FeatureCollection;
    }
```

I don't know what to do. swift is changed every beta.

Comment: 'features' is an array, not a dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

As @Kirsteins said is his answer, you have to do a lot of unwrapping, and it's recommended to use a JSON library.

If you still want to stick with hand made extraction, then I suggest you to made it programmatically, such as adding an extension to `NSDictionary` as follows:

```
extension NSDictionary {
    func objectForTreeKeys<T>(keys:[String]) -> T? {
        var dict: NSDictionary? = self
        var retValue: T?

        for key in keys {
            var value: AnyObject? = dict?.objectForKey(key)

            if let unwrapped = value as? NSDictionary {
                dict = unwrapped
            } else if let unwrapped = value as? T {
                retValue = unwrapped
                break
            } else {
                retValue = nil
                break
            }
        }

        return retValue
    }
}
```

You pass an array of keys to the function, and it traverses all nested dictionaries until:

- a value of type `T` is encountered
- a value having type different than `NSDictionary` and `T` is found
- a `nil` value is found

In the first case, it returns the value of `T` type - in the other cases it returns `nil`.

You can use it as follows:

```
let ret: String? = jsonResult.objectForTreeKeys(["features", "properties", "alert"])
```

As you can see, it's a generic method, and the return type is inferred from the type of the variable the result is assigned to - so it's necessary to explicitly define its type, which must be optional (`String?` in this specific case).